# What class does the .NET framework use to extract Data Annotations information from a class?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a situation in which I need to extract Data Annotations information from an ASP.NET ViewModel in order to perform some more advanced validations.

Instead of writing my own type descriptor class, I wonder if I can use the native one.

Even though Data Annotations are not tied to ASP.NET MVC, if there is some ASP.NET MVC specific implementation, that wouldn't be a problem to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is all done through reflection.

Comment: @Oded. I know but Microsoft must have implemented a Type Descriptor class the encapsulates this logic. It's just impratical to write it all over again every time you need to know if a property is required and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, ASP.NET MVC did create a helper to class called [ModelMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx) to extract meta information from model, considering data annotation attributes. See the example:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(AppointmentViewModel formModel)
        {
            var metaInfo = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<AppointmentViewModel, DateTime>(model => model.Date, null);
            var dateIsRequired = metaInfo.IsRequired;

            // do some logic here..

            return this.Edit(formModel);
        }
```

This reduces the need of manually reading the data-annotation attributes for the basic scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Data annotations are just normal attributes and can be accessed using the normal reflection mechanisms for attributes.

See [`Accessing Custom Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379.aspx) on MSDN and [Chapter 18](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html) of Programming C#.

Comment: As I said, I know I can write a type descriptor class that reads the attributes.. I'm asking if there's some already baked inside the framework

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I ended up finding what I needed. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations contains the class [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) which is used to validate an object or property of an object that is decorated with ValidationAttributes.

I think this class is used by the most parts (ASP.NET MVC, WCF RIA Services, etc.) of the framework that rely on Validation logic.

If you want to extend the basic validation functionality you could write your own [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx)s and let the Validator check your objects.